# Trouble trying to store an image and store the information in the database table

Tags: laravel-7

I have set up a new form to allow someone to add a profile for who a user will manage.

Its a pretty simple form with 4 fields, name, avatar, sport and description

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('add') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"
                                    for="avatar"
                            >
                                Avatar
                            </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('name') }}"
                                        type="file"
                                        name="avatar"
                                        id="avatar"
                                >

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Sport') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="sport" id="sport" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                    <option value="Football">Football</option>
                                    <option value="Cricket">Cricket</option>
                                    <option value="Hockey">Hockey</option>
                                    <option value="Basketball">Basketball</option>
                                </select>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="description" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Description') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="description" type="textarea" class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" name="description" required>

                                @error('description')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Save') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

The controller I have added is as follows

```
public function create()
    {
        //dd(request());

        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'avatar' => ['file'],
            'sport' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (request('avatar'))
        {
            $attributes['avatar'] = request('avatar')->store('avatars');
        }

        Players::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'name' => $attributes['name'],
            'avatar' => $attributes['avatar'],
            'sport' => $attributes['sport'],
            'description' => $attributes['description']
        ]);


        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Every time I go to submit the form I get a 302 and it returns back to the add form.

If I hardcode a value for 'avatar' => $attributes['avatar'] it adds the record to the table fine, except for the file will not upload into the director.

I am working on my local machine.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: so you are saying that `request('avatar')->store('avatars')` is returning a path that is been saved on the db, but that the file is not been saved on that path?

Comment: No it doesnt look like its returning a path at all.  Im a bit of a newb and tried to follow a few tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads), you need first to get the `file` form the request:

```
$attributes['avatar'] = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- missing
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didnt seem to work, but does make sense to me and should work.

I just adapted the code a little to         

$attributes['avatar'] = request('avatar');

It now saves the filename to the table

I think I am having issues saving the file itself

Comment: @GlennCoyle so even with this line, the "avatar" field on the database is empty?

Comment: yea, it returns back to the add form and throws a 302.  Im starting to think i have not set up the file store properly

Comment: I think i figured it out, i forgot to add the following to the form enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @GlennCoyle yes you have to add it to the form otherwise laravel won't accept files in the request... also add [`sometimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if I hadnt set the right things up on the form.

Still have issues with storing the files but would like to try and resolve that myself so that I can learn by doing.

I appreciate everyone's help